# Problem with NSString

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have done this many times before and never got a issue but i have got a problem now i just cant solve.

I have a NSMutableString declared in the H File. Named TheString.
I have a IBOutlet of a UItextfield declared named TextField
In viewdidload i fill this string with some text. That goes fine and when i NSLOG it everything works.

Then on a button press i do:

```
TheString = [TheString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"And"
withString:TextField.text];
```

I have done this loads of times and it always works. However this time i build the app with no errors and press the button and it crashes. I checked the console and there are no errors when it crashes.
EDIT

In the H File i have this also:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *TheString;
```

And in viewdidload i do this

```
TheString = [NSMutableString alloc];
```

And i synthesize
I give it some text and NSLOG it and it is all working.
If anyone could please help me with this it would be great!

Thanks

Comment: What is the backtrace you get in XCode? There is always some kind of backtrace. But it looks like you did not connect the IBOutlet in the UIBuilder.

Comment: Put an NSlog or breakpoint in the button handler and see if it is called. Also check whether TheString is alloced and retained properly since you said it is declared in H file.

Comment: Add the code where you init the TheString

Comment: The outlet is connected, And i have tried clean build and run. Thanks for the answers thou. I Will edit my original post with init code. Thanks for the answers and replies!

Comment: You need to show more code, and since you're crashing you should show the relevant portion of the stack trace as @grundprinzip requested.

Comment: Ok ill Debug and set a breakpoint and see what errors i get, Thanks!

Comment: I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the console and it seems to end at obj_msgsend?

Comment: I have tried that, i have also tried it as a NSString and Not A NSSmutableString but no different. thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Have you allocated `TheString`.

Try this

```
TheString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Some text here"];
TheString = [TheString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"And" withString:TextField.text];
```

Make sure you `release` it when you are done using it

Comment: Note that you're leaking the original string in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

This `TheString = [NSMutableString alloc];` should not be done. Change it to

```
TheString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

and after button event call

```
[TheString replaceOccurrencesOfString: @"And" 
withString: TextField.text options: 0 range: NSMakeRange(0, [receiver length])];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried that but it is no different.

Comment: Check with the debugger if TextField.text is nil.

Comment: 2 answers to one question..@dasdom if you wont to improve/change your answer edit your original answer itself. Not spam the forum by giving multiple answers

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Ok, sorry. I did not want to spam the forum. I thought this answer is kind of another topic. Wont to that in future.

Comment: then delete the answer which you feel doesnt answer the question